# Selecting a subset of columns in R data.table using a vector with a constant column

Tags: r, data.table

In `data.table`, one can use the `with = FALSE` to select columns using a vector. For instance:

```
dt <- data.table(one = 1:3, two = 2:4, three = 3:5)
dt[, .(one, three)]
parlist <- c("one", "three")
dt[, parlist, with = FALSE]
```

One can also use the `j` argument to add a new, constant column:

```
dt[, .(one, new = 10)]
```

But is it possible to combine the two? I.e., use a vector to select the columns, but such that it includes a new, constant column. Solutions like `parlist <- c("one", "new" = 10)` do not seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine `.SDcols` with `c(.SD, .(new=10))`:

```r
dt <- data.table(one = 1:3, two = 2:4, three = 3:5)
parlist <- c("one", "three")

dt[, c(.SD, .(new = 10)), .SDcols = parlist]
#      one three   new
#    <int> <int> <num>
# 1:     1     3    10
# 2:     2     4    10
# 3:     3     5    10
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That works, but unfortunately doesn't solve the issue of having different `parlist`s with the _same_ syntax used in subsetting `dt`. (Or at least I don't see how it can be solved.) For instance, say you have `parlists <- list(c("one", "new1" = 10), c("one", "new2" = 20))` and you want something along the lines `lapply(parlists, function(parlist) dt[, parlist, with = FALSE])`.

Comment: One issue is that you have either fields as names (`"new1"=10`) or fields as values (`"one"`). We can work around this by assigning `NA` to the latter, ignoring its value if present in the original `dt`. Try: `parlists <- list(c("one"=NA, "new1"=10), c("one"=NA, "new2"=20)); lapply(parlists, function(parlist) dt[, c(.SD, parlist[setdiff(names(parlist), names(dt))]), .SDcols = intersect(names(parlist), names(dt))])`. But that wasn't in your original question ...

Comment: You're right. My minimal example was a bit too minimal, sorry! I just have one last question (and sorry for extending the scope again): is it possible to _rename_ some already existing columns in the same way? Something like `parlists <- list(c("one"=NA, "new1"=10, "new3" = "two"), c("one"=NA, "new2"=20, "new4" = "two"))`... Because `dt[, .(one, new1 = 10, new3 = two)]` works. Thank you again.

Comment: Now you're getting complicated. I suggest that the yet-unreleased `data.table-1.14.3` provides an `env=` argument which will likely be useful here. I don't see an easy way without writing a bespoke function for it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll be looking forward to that update, in the meantime, I accept your answer. Thank you again.